# Does $f_n(x)=n[f(x+n^{-1})-f(x)]$ converges uniformly to $f'(x)$ as $n\to\infty$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Well, the title says it all.

Is it true? If yes, how do I prove it?
If not, why? What restrictions should $f$ have so it is true?

Thanks!

Comment: Any thoughts? MSE like to see effort before giving hints and whatnot.

Comment: Try $f(x)=x^3$.

Comment: What are the hypotheses on $f$, what domain are you talking about, etc. The problem is unclear at this point

Comment: Its not a problem from any book or class. It is just a thought that came on my mind.

Comment: Fine, but surely you can see your question should have the form "Suppose A is true. Is B true?$" You've described B, sort of, but there is no A.

Comment: Probably, in your book there is a theorem that says that uniform limit over any metric space of continuous functions is continuous. So, clearly the answer is no every time $f'$ is not $C^1$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x) = x^3$. Then $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{3x}{n}+3x^2$. Thus the limit is not uniformly convergent because of the $\frac{3x}{n}$ term.

Comment: Then the theorem is false for some functions. When is it true?

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro It's true if $f'$ is uniformly continuous. You can prove that using the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: I will try to do it!